# How to express the paradoxical situation in idiom or proper sentences?

Tags: idioms, paraphrasing

I would like to know how to express the situation described below either with a better paraphrase, or perhaps by using a relevant idiom.

> We've introduced a something with the expectation that others profit
>   from it, but it is abused in an unintentional way.

Comment: Something along the lines of "We let them profit from it, and the next thing you know, they hit you below the belt" perhaps...

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. Is it a formal way to say that is exploited under malicious intention? I mean hit you below the belt. Thanks

Comment: On a side note, you have not introduced _a_ something, you have introduced something. No need for that article there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean that it is abused in a way that you didn't foresee. This is often called the **law of unintended consequences**, and it is often cited for government policies and projects that have effects not only unanticipated but antithetical to the original aims of the implementers. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unintended_consequences) has a good overview and history of the phrase.

Comment: Wow cool. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot